Condition-based table column calculation
I have a data table with three columns:
t = [
datum,meter-reading,meter-exchange
25-Sep-2012,2.6,0
13-Oct-2013,12.0,0
28-Oct-2013,14.4,0
01-Nov-2013,14.2,1
12-Dec-2013,0.1,0
23-Feb-2014,0.9,0
15-Jun-2014,3.0,0
15-Sep-2014,6.0,0
23-Jun-2015,8.7,0
06-Oct-2015,10.2,0
...
]

Is there any neat way to create a new table (matrix) where the yearly consumption is calculated with the meter-readings including possible meter changes (meter exchanged "1" in column 3).
The consumption is calculated by the difference of the latest meter reading in one year  and the latest meter reading in the year before. But when the meter is exchanged the consumption is calculated slightly differently (if change is "1", take difference from the meter reading of that date with last meter reading of the year before plus the last meter reading of the same year.
Expected result is (ignoring first year 2012):
t1 = [
year,consumption
2013,11.7
2014,5.9
2015,4.2
...
]

